# Why does this CompletableFuture not execute with a shared ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm playing with an idea I have for a dataflow language and I'm trying to use a an executor service to limit the number of available threads to the number of cores on my system and create a shared pool of threads.

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
 Function a = new Function("A", service);
 Function b = new Function("B", service);
 Function c = new Function("C", service);
 a.addObserver(b);
 a.addObserver(c);
 a.change()
```

A is changed causing it to call it's `evaluate()`, then B and C are notified they need to update and they do.

In `Function.java` I have:

```
 public class Function implements Func{
    private boolean isComplete;
    private Set<Func> dependsOn;
    private Set<Func> observedBy;
    private ExecutorService service;

    public Function(String name, ExecutorService service){
        observedBy = new HashSet<>();
        dependsOn = new HashSet<>();
        this.isComplete = false;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void addObserver(Func f){
        observedBy.add(f);
        f.addDependency(this);
    }

    private void evaluate() {
        boolean match = dependsOn.stream().allMatch(Func::isComplete);

        if (match) {
            this.isComplete = false;

            // inform each observer that I'm about to start to evaluate
            observedBy.forEach(func -> func.onDependentEvaluate(this));

            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Doing some work");
                    int sleepTime = (int) (Math.random() * 5000);
                    System.out.println("Working for " + sleepTime);
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, service).thenRun(this::onComplete);
        }
    }

    public void addDependency(Func f){
        dependsOn.add(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void change() {;
        evaluate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        this.isComplete = true;
        observedBy.forEach((f) -> f.onDependentComplete(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentEvaluate(Func f) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentComplete(Func func){
        evaluate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isComplete() {
        return this.isComplete;
    }
}
```

When I pass `service` to `runAsync`, only A executes. If I don't pass `service` and the CompletableFuture uses the ForkJoin.commonPool, the graph will execute as I expect. Is there a different way to share the `ExecutorService`? Any ideas why the next Futures don't get executed?

Comment: It's a class called `Function`

Comment: I get that, but we really can't help unless we know what the class is doing.

Comment: @JeffreyGuenther There's your answer, took me longer than expected. Can you please delete your obsolete comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is much simpler than you think it is. **tl;dr** your only problem is that you aren't shutting down the `ExecutorService`, so your program doesn't terminate.

**Long version:** In my environment, this program works as expected, and tasks `B` and `C` do, in fact, run. I have refactored your code to allow me to create an `AbstractFunction`, allowing me to override the behavior of what `Function` actually does, e.g.

```
public abstract class AbstractFunction implements Func {
  protected boolean isComplete;
  protected Set<Func> dependsOn;
  protected Set<Func> observedBy;
  protected ExecutorService service;
  protected String name;

  public AbstractFunction(String name, ExecutorService service) {
    observedBy = new HashSet<>();
    dependsOn = new HashSet<>();
    this.isComplete = false;
    this.service = service;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void addObserver(Func f) {
    observedBy.add(f);
    f.addDependency(this);
  }

  public void addDependency(Func f) {
    dependsOn.add(f);
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
    this.isComplete = true;
    observedBy.forEach((f) -> f.onDependentComplete(this));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isComplete() {
    return this.isComplete;
  }

  @Override
  public void change() { }

  @Override
  public void onDependentEvaluate(Func f) { }

  @Override
  public void onDependentComplete(Func func) { }
}
```

So, your original (effectively unchanged) `Function` is now this:

```
public class Function extends AbstractFunction implements Func {
  public Function(String name, ExecutorService service) {
    super(name, service);
  }

  protected void evaluate() {
    boolean match = dependsOn.stream().allMatch(Func::isComplete);

    if (match) {
      this.isComplete = false;

      // inform each observer that I'm about to start to evaluate
      observedBy.forEach(func -> func.onDependentEvaluate(this));

      CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
          System.out.println("Doing some work");
          int sleepTime = (int) (Math.random() * 5000);
          System.out.println("Working for " + sleepTime);
          Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println("I was interrupted, my name is: " + name);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }, service).thenRun(this::onComplete);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void change() {
    evaluate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDependentComplete(Func f) {
    evaluate();
  }
}
```

Given this new structure, I create a `ShutdownFunc` to listen and shut the executor service when `"C"` finishes, i.e.

```
public class ShutdownFunc extends AbstractFunction {
  public ShutdownFunc(String name, ExecutorService service) {
    super(name, service);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDependentComplete(Func f) {
    System.out.println("Shutting down the system");
    try {
      service.shutdown();
      service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And main of course:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime()
        .availableProcessors());
    Function a = new Function("A", service);
    Function b = new Function("B", service);
    Function c = new Function("C", service);
    a.addObserver(b);
    a.addObserver(c);

    Func d = new ShutdownFunc("D", service);
    c.addObserver(d);

    a.change();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Doing some work
Working for 4315
Doing some work
Working for 2074
Doing some work
Working for 2884
Shutting down the system
```

And the program correctly waits for completion, then terminates gracefully.

Comment: Nice sol'n! I actually have `service.shutdown()` as the last line of my main method, but missed it in my copy-paste. Your solution pointed me in the right direction. If I call `service.shutdown()` in my main method, it shuts down the service even though a new task was just submit, thus causing B to never execute.